# FA Jasmine spec timed out. Resetting the WebDriver Control Flow.- Error Message

Tags: protractor, timeout

I was trying to automate a website and after the initial authentication on login page...as soon as I enter the home page this error comes up:

**FA Jasmine spec timed out. Resetting the WebDriver Control Flow.**

what could be the reason??

Comment: Could you please provide some code or what the spec (`it` block) looks like? and also what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

One of your promises is being rejected because of which the spec is getting timed out. If you are waiting for a promise to return a response that never arrives, the spec does not go forward. This is a generic problem with automation testing using protractor.

You can completely remove this problem by shifting your codebase to use async await. Since protractor does not support promise manager anymore, you will eventually have to move to async await. What async await does is that it will wait for any promise to be resolved before moving ahead with the code execution. That way you will not miss any promises and your spec will never timeout.